# How can I prevent turning off the locations services on managed iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

Is it possible to disallow iPhone/iPad users to turn off the location services on their iDevices?

E.g. by configuring profiles, software or system settings, etc.

I have a client that needs to track the GPS location of their employees and doesn't want them to be able to turn off the location services in the iPhone settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the only way that I could find out was to use password protected Restrictions. Looks like I have to manually set the Restrictions password on each device and then turn on the Location services restriction. If anyone comes up with a better solutions, please let me know.

Comment: You can use Apple Configurator to load a saved image on to the devices. You can have Restrictions turned on with your settings pre-configured along with many others. You don't need to Supervise or have any profiles loaded.